# Why is my While loop not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a game that gives you the chance to critical hit , normal hit or hit something. Now I think it has to do with the variable within the if/else. This is my code:

```
    var chance =  parseInt(Math.random() * 10);    
    var hpDummy = 10;

while ( hpDummy >=1)
{

    if(chance >= 5 && chance <7)
     {   
    alert("You throw a punch at the dummy! You graze it's nose dealing 1 damage");
    var hpDummy = hpDummy -1;
     }

    else if (chance >=7)
    {
    alert("You throw a punch at the dummy! You directly hit its jaw dealing 2 damage ! AMAZING shot ! ");
    var hpDummy = hpDummy -2;
    }

    else 
    {
    alert("You completely miss the dummy almost hitting Welt !");
    var hpDummy = hpDummy -0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wtf foes 'hpDummy -0' do???

Comment: try to explain more what does that function does currently and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Probably, you should generate a new random number at each iteration. Otherwise it will always be the same.

Comment: Well i'ma noob at it yes... now i just re-read my code and indeed the 'hpDummy -0" is quite useless. now what i want my code to do is while the dummy's hp is above 1 you keep getting the chance to hit it. the random number i generated makes you critical hit it doing -2 or normal hit it -1. if the dummy's hp reaches 0 the story goes on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `chance` variable inside the function. If your `chance` variable has value less than 5 then it will become infinite loop. So try something like this

```
 var hpDummy = 10;
 while (hpDummy >= 1) {
     var chance = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
     if (chance >= 5 && chance < 7) {
         alert("You throw a punch at the dummy! You graze it's nose dealing 1 damage");
         var hpDummy = hpDummy - 1;
     } else if (chance >= 7) {
         alert("You throw a punch at the dummy! You directly hit its jaw dealing 2 damage ! AMAZING shot ! ");
         var hpDummy = hpDummy - 2;
     } else {
         alert("You completely miss the dummy almost hitting Welt !");
     }
 }
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L67xy3s8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
   var hpDummy = 10;

while ( hpDummy >=1){

  var chance =  Math.round(Math.random() * 10);    


    if(chance >= 5 && chance <7)
     {   
    console.log("You throw a punch at the dummy! You graze it's nose dealing 1 damage");
    var hpDummy = hpDummy -1;
     }

    else if (chance >=7)
    {
    console.log("You throw a punch at the dummy! You directly hit its jaw dealing 2 damage ! AMAZING shot ! ");
    var hpDummy = hpDummy -2;
    }

    else 
    {
    console.log("You completely miss the dummy almost hitting Welt !");
    }
}
```

I am using console.log instead of alert. Press F12 > Console to see results. 
There is Math.round to really round the random number. And the `var chance` must be randomly recalculated each time in while loop.